# Input list problems with datalist

Tags: php

I read some data out from my database and want to list the result in a dropdown list in order to shorten the keying for the user

```
echo '<input list "orte" name="ort" id="ort">';
echo '<datalist id="orte">';
$klt = mysql_query_log("select distinct Ort from kulturevent where Mandant = ?Mandant order by Ort", array('Mandant'=>$usrrow['Mandant']));
while ($kulrow = mysqli_fetch_array($klt)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$kulrow['Ort'].'">';
}
echo '</datalist>';
```

Neither using the down arrow nor a single key addressing one of the found towns show a valid result

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: What is `<datalist>` ?

Comment: It does not appear cause you don't have data. Your query is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget an equal sign in your input list.
It should be:

```
echo '<input list="orte" name="ort" id="ort">';
```